# Add/Remove Columns/elements between two Tables/ObjectContainer, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to ask you if someone knows a webcomponent like this one, because I'm sure there is one, I'll describe the behavior below.

Here is the image:

[image]

When you click an element/column of `A` Table and then you click on `To the right Button` it should move to the right, and viceversa. 
 So if you know how can I achieve this, it will be fantastic, also if you know a component that I can use (instead of create, pure javascript or jQuery)
that would be great. 
NOTE: I need it with the buttons, not drag and drop.

Comment: Please submit the code you tried using, then we will help you correct it. If you don't have any code, I'm afraid this is the wrong place to post. I'm sure there's a place that'll do all of the code for you somewhere out there...

Comment: The logic should be something like this.
1. Convert all elements to checkboxes
2. Add 2 event handler on the buttons(left and right)
if (left)
Search for checked boxes in B, remove from B and append to A
else
Search for checked boxes in A, remove from A and append to B

Comment: @zer00ne I was asking for examples cuz Im actually developing on a new private Framework, and I already saw some tables like that, I was specting to see a library, not to program , sorry if I didn't explane as well, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, please check the live example below:

```js
$('#multiselect').multiselect();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Two-side-Multi-Select-Plugin-with-jQuery-multiselect-js/js/multiselect.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <select name="from[]" id="multiselect" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">Columns1/elements1</option>
      <option value="2">Columns2/elements2</option>
      <option value="3">Columns3/elements3</option>
      <option value="4">Columns4/elements4</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button type="button" id="multiselect_rightAll" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="multiselect_rightSelected" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="multiselect_leftSelected" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="multiselect_leftAll" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <select name="to[]" id="multiselect_to" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this will help you.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
var selectedElement = '';
$(document).on("click", "td", function() { 
 selectedElement = this;
});
$(document).on("click", ".right", function() { 
 if(selectedElement && selectedElement.innerHTML && selectedElement.parentElement.parentNode.parentNode.id != "table2") {
   $("#table2 tbody").append("<tr><td>" + selectedElement.innerHTML + "</td></tr>");
   $(selectedElement).remove();
   selectedElement = '';
 }
});
$(document).on("click", ".left", function() { 
 if(selectedElement && selectedElement.innerHTML && selectedElement.parentElement.parentNode.parentNode.id != "table1") {
   $("#table1 tbody").append("<tr><td>" + selectedElement.innerHTML + "</td></tr>");
   $(selectedElement).remove();
   selectedElement = '';
 }
});
</script>
<style>
  td:active {
    background-color : #87CEEB;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" style="width:100%">    
<div class="leftCont" style="width:30%">      
  <table class="table" id="table1" style="width:30%;float:left">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Columns1/elements1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Columns2/elements2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Columns3/elements3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="middleCont" style="width:100px;float:left;margin: 50px 120px 50px 120px;display: inline-grid;"> 
  <button class="right" value="right">Right</button><br>
  <button class="left" value="left">Left</button>
</div>
<div class="rigthCont" style="width:30%;float:left"> 
  <table class="table" id="table2" style="width:30%;float:left">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>B</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to make you guys code for me, I tryed to ask you if there is a library, sorry if I miss explain. but thanks for the example, that was exactly what I needed